# How do you apply regex to value in database to query against in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, mongodb

Here is the scenario, you are storing phone numbers in mongo as a string. Values could be any of the following:

- 987-654-3210
- 9876543210
- (978) 654-3210

All of these numbers are the same. I want to search using a RegExp which will basically strip the value of all non alphanumeric characters. Searching using 987-654-3210 will return 9876543210, but that's it. I'm hoping to find a solution where the regex will be applied to what is stored in the database to match the regexp that I'm passing in the query.

Ultimately, if all three of those phone numbers are in the database and the user searches using any of the three, all three should be returned.

Comment: To clarify, I understand how to replace the search value to just be digits, but comparing that value of just digits will not match values in the database that contain dashes and parentheses. The challenge is being able to match the 3 values in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use those 3 regex that will extract the 3 expected groups (in your example `987`, `654` and `3210`) :

- XXX-XXX-XXXX : `/(\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{4})/g`
- XXXXXXXXX : `/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/g`
- (XXX) XXX-XXXX : `/\((\d{3})\)\s(\d{3})-(\d{4})/g`

The idea is to generate those 3 groups from your input and generate the three format from these groups to `find` all documents matching any of those three formats :

```
var input = "987-654-3210"; // or any of the 3 formats

var regex = [];
regex[0] = /(\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{4})/g;      // 987-654-3210
regex[1] = /(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/g;        // 9876543210
regex[2] = /\((\d{3})\)\s(\d{3})-(\d{4})/g; // (978) 654-3210

function getPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {
    for (key in regex) {
        var match = regex[key].exec(phoneNumber);
        if (match) {
            return match;
        }
    }
}

var group = getPhoneNumber(input);

var filter = [];
filter[0] = group[1] + "-" + group[2] + "-" + group[3];
filter[1] = group[1] + group[2] + group[3];
filter[2] = "(" + group[1] + ") " + group[2] + "-" + group[3];

db.data.find({
    "phoneNumber": {
        "$in": filter
    }
})
```

You can try it directly in the mongodb shell

Comment: This will help me get started, but I'm ultimately hoping to be able to apply a pattern to what is already in the database so that if they are using periods instead of dashes or something like that, I'd be able to find more patterns. But perhaps just restricting how the data is stored in the database may help in the search.